# DecimalFormat empty string to null conversion

Tags: java, formatting, type-conversion, opencsv, decimalformat

I'm using `DecimalFormat` with the pattern `"0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000"` to parse `BigDecimal`. I have a special case when the input string is "". Here it fails with `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: ""`.

My question is if this is possible to handle this special case using only pattern definition. I need to convert `""` to `null`.

Note: Actually I'm using open csv library, annotaion `@CsvNumber("0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000")`. Under the hood it used `DecimalFormat`, that's why I have the access only to pattern definition.

Comment: Are you not able to catch the exception and set it to `null` yourself?

Comment: No, I need it to terminate correctly. Actually I need to know if pattern definition permits to do this check. Don't found anything in documentation.

Comment: The source code is well documented, you could contribute a new option to the `@CsvNumber` annotation (such as `valueIfEmpty=`) without too much difficulty.

Comment: Didn't think about that. Actually inside open csv I found where to apply this minor change. Will look in this direction. Thanks.